# ERROR ORA-29266

Tags: oracle, webservice, http, oracle-11g

¿alguien sabe la solución de este error? Ya que buscando, la única solución que encuentro es

> if the end of the HTTP response is reached prematurely
>
> check if the HTTP response terminates prematurely

No se a que se refiera con eso o como darle una solución; dicho procedimiento sera llamado desde una aplicacion para su consumo.

```
ERROR   end-of-body reached

CAUSE   The end of the HTTP response body was reached.

ACTION  If the end of the HTTP response is reached prematurely, check if 
        the HTTP response terminates prematurely. Otherwise, end 
        the HTTP response.
```

Agrego código utilizado para el consumo de el web service.

```
PROCEDURE SP_CANCELA_COMPROMETIDO (P_SOCIEDAD     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                P_EJERCICIO     IN  NUMBER,
                                P_FOLIOUNICO     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                P_USULLAVE         IN     VARCHAR2,
                                P_RESPUESTA     OUT NUMBER,
                                P_MENSAJE       OUT CLOB)
IS
    V_SOAP_REQ       CLOB;
    V_SOAP_RESP      CLOB;
    REQ              UTL_HTTP.REQ;
    RESP             UTL_HTTP.RESP;
    V_URL            VARCHAR2 (32760);
    V_USR            VARCHAR2 (1024);
    V_PWD            VARCHAR2 (1024);
    V_METODO         VARCHAR2 (1024) := 'CommitmentCancelSimple';
    V_TIPO_METODO    VARCHAR2 (1024) := 'DELETE';
    P_X_CSRF_TOKEN   VARCHAR2 (1024);
    P_COOKIE         VARCHAR2 (1024);

BEGIN

    V_PARAMETROS :=
    'P_SOCIEDAD = '
    || P_SOCIEDAD
    || ' , P_EJERCICIO = '
    || P_EJERCICIO
    || ' , P_FOLIOUNICO = '
    || P_FOLIOUNICO
    || ' , P_USULLAVE = '
    || P_USULLAVE
    || ' , P_RESPUESTA= '
    || P_RESPUESTA
    || ' , P_MENSAJE= '
    || P_MENSAJE;

    V_SOAP_REQ := ''; V_URL:='https://fioqa01.sistemasbo.corp:8001/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGW_BCS_INTEGRATION_SRV/';--URL del servicio OData de SAP BCS
    V_USR := 'xxx';
    V_PWD := 'xxxxxxxx';

    SP_GET_TOKEN_COOKIE (P_USULLAVE,
                         P_RESPUESTA,
                         P_MENSAJE,
                         P_X_CSRF_TOKEN,
                         P_COOKIE);

    IF P_RESPUESTA = PROCESO_FALLIDO
    THEN
         ERROR_SECCIONES := P_MENSAJE;
    RAISE EXCEPTION_PERSONALIZADA;
    END IF;

    V_SOAP_REQ :='(Sociedad='''||P_SOCIEDAD||''',Ejercicio='''||P_EJERCICIO||''',FolioUnico='''||P_FOLIOUNICO||''',UsuarioRegistro='''||P_USULLAVE||''')';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('V_SOAP_REQ_ISAAC :' || V_SOAP_REQ);
    INSERT INTO LOG_ERRORESBD (LOG_PROCEDIMIENTO,
                                    LOG_PARAMETROS,
                                    USUARIOID,
                                    LOG_ERROR)
    VALUES ('01. SP_CANCELA_COMPROMETIDO - V_SOAP_REQ',
            V_PARAMETROS,
            P_USULLAVE,
            'V_SOAP_REQ : '||V_SOAP_REQ);
    COMMIT;

 OData en una sola linea
    V_URL := V_URL || V_METODO ||V_SOAP_REQ;
   UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('file:/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/owm/wallets/certificados/bibliotk/','xxxxxxxxxxxx');

    REQ := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST (V_URL, V_TIPO_METODO);
   UTL_HTTP.SET_AUTHENTICATION (REQ,V_USR,V_PWD,'Basic',FALSE);
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (REQ, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (REQ, 'x-csrf-token', P_X_CSRF_TOKEN);
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (REQ, 'Cookie', P_COOKIE);
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER (REQ, 'Content-Length', LENGTH (V_SOAP_REQ)); 
    UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT (REQ, V_SOAP_REQ);
    RESP := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE (REQ);
    UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT (RESP, V_SOAP_RESP);

   UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE (RESP);
    P_RESPUESTA := PROCESO_EXITOSO;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN EXCEPTION_PERSONALIZADA
      THEN
         P_RESPUESTA := PROCESO_FALLIDO;
         P_MENSAJE := ERROR_SECCIONES;
         ERROR_INTERNO :=
               'ERROR INTERNO EN SP_CANCELA_COMPROMETIDO: '
            || ERROR_SECCIONES
            || 'ERROR ORACLE: '
            || ERRORORACLE;
         ROLLBACK;

      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         P_RESPUESTA := PROCESO_FALLIDO;
         P_MENSAJE := 'ERROR AL EJECUTAR SP_CANCELA_COMPROMETIDO';
         ERROR_INTERNO := 'ERROR INTERNO EN SP_CANCELA_COMPROMETIDO: ' || SQLERRM;
         ROLLBACK;

   END;
```

Comment: si agregar mas infomacion de lo que estan intentando hacer?

Comment: Podes aclarar que estas haciendo para que de ese error?

Comment: @Bryro Claro estoy intentando consumir un web service, pero al intentarlo ejecutar me manda dicho error y esto solo sucede en el método DELETE, modifico la publicacion para agregar el codigo utilizado